# How to find the percentage share of a field in Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame like  below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID" : [1,2,3,4],
                   "Amt" : [100, 200,  300, 400]})
```

My obejective is to find the percentage share of each amount and create a new field in this dataframe with it. My final DataFrame should look like

```
ID Amt Avg
1  100 10
2  200 20
3  300 30
4  400 40
```

To achieve this, I concatenated the Amt field to  same DF. Then renamed it to Avg. and then calculated the perc using iterator

```py
   df = pd.concat([df, df['Amt']], axis=1)
   df.columns=(['ID', 'Amt', 'Avg'])
   for i in range(0,len(df)):
       df['Avg'] = ((df['Avg']/df['Amt'].sum())*100)
```

I'm new to this. I've seen many achieve difficult objective with much simpler code.
So can someone please help me to know the better approach than this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
df['Avg'] = df['Amt']/df['Amt'].sum()*100
print (df)
   ID  Amt   Avg
0   1  100  10.0
1   2  200  20.0
2   3  300  30.0
3   4  400  40.0
```